# MS Excel add-in Datastream doesn't send CR LF characters to serial line

Tags: excel, vba, serial-port, excel-addins, com-port

I want to exchange data between MS Excel (VBA) and my STM32 Nucleo via serial line (virtual COM port). I am using MS Excel add-in Datastream from Microsoft which, according to them, is intended for this. I found that the add-in is unable to send CR and LF appended to message. It leaves them out.

According to the port monitoring SW I use, the add-in always sends 0x0A (LF) at the end even when it is not in the message. Conversely, if I add the characters 0x0D (CR) or 0x0A (LF) to the message it omits them completely. Other characters like 0x09, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0E will send without any problem. Have you encountered such a problem? Can you advise me how to force it to send these characters? Thanks.